# How to validate a pair of values from the same Model?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**Use case**
My use case is that I need to validate a Table Tennis score.

**Form**

```
<input name="data[MatchesPlayer][1][score]" type="number" id="MatchesPlayer1Score">
<input name="data[MatchesPlayer][2][score]" type="number" id="MatchesPlayer2Score">
```

**Constraints**

- One score must be bigger than 11.
- One score must be 2 points or greater than the other if the score is higher than 11.

**Problem**
When cake validates multiple rows from the same model, the model data is set to that record. This means that it's not possible to compare the two values as they aren't both available in `$this->data`. As I am using `saveAll()` each record is set to the model and then validated before it's saved.

**Question**
I'd like to know if there is a good way to validate this pair of data without resorting to saving it into the session or similar before I can validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I normally do here is I create a wrapper for the `save` method. This allows me to perform custom manipulation that would otherwise not be possible with model callbacks, or even use custom transactions etc.

In your case, it would be something like:

```
class MatchesPlayer extends Model {

    protected $_saveData = null;

    public function updateScore($data) {
        $this->_saveData = $data;
        try {
            // You can use saveAll to validate
            // only, and not actually save
            $saved = $this->saveAll($data, array('validate' => 'only'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Catch exceptions here in case the
            // saveAll is instead something that throws Exceptions
            // Or your database uses exceptions
            $saved = false;
        }

        $this->_saveData = null;
        return $saved
    }
}
```

You could then use `$this->_saveData` across the model. If you want to be clever with this, you could detect all sub-models that are being saved in the `$data` and then set the `$this->_saveData` on those as well - I would make this an `AppModel` method of course.

Note that you may want to throw exceptions from this `updateScore()` method when validation fails. Throwing an exception if validation fails - vs save - would allow you to set a custom flash message for the user as well, or even have an api that responds with a different status code.

Comment: Sweet, it's inline with what I was thinking but better. I was setting the data to the model in my controller before saving. I think this is a bit slicker.

Answer (score -1):

Use custom validation rules in MatchesPlayer model, please check 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: This will not work because of the way that each row of data from the same model is set to the model for each validation even in a custom validation method, you will not be able to compare the data without saving it to the model first.

Comment: In this case you can create a single variable from two scores before saving 
$this->request->data['MatchesPlayer']['score'] = $this->data['MatchesPlayer']['1']['score']."_".$this->data['MatchesPlayer']['2']['score'];

and the apply custom validations on $this->request->data['MatchesPlayer']['score'] 

in custom function explode score by _